# 2 terminal SMD resistor marking code with Omega+F

Tags: resistors, surface-mount, markings

What kind of code are the markings on the resistors in the picture?

I think they write out the Omega symbol, just because there is enough space on the component and looks nice, but I was not able to find any matching result online about the meaning of the letter 'F' and 'J'.

What kind of marking system is it?

[image: smd]

Comment: Could be a date code, lot code, manufacturing site code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

One likely option is tolerance code. F = 1% and J = 5%.

Comment: +1, a reference for this: http://www.koaspeer.com/catimages/Products/SLW07-SLW1-SLN3-SLN5/SLW07-SLW1-SLN3-SLN5.pdf